# MySQL 5.6 Performance Tuning Issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, performance, performance-tuning

I have read and try lots of things about MySQL optimization and tuning. I tried most of them one by one according to our needs but nearly I got nothing.

I am doing my test using some simulation program with 800 concurrent user. However, system should be able to handle about 1500 concurrent user.

System specs:

```
OS: OpenSUSE 13.1 x86_64
MySQL: 5.6.27-log openSUSE package 
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v2 @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 64GB
DB size: ~6GB
Tables: 870
Storage: Raid 6 // I know 10 is most powerful for DBs but it is not my choice
```

All tables are InnoDB and here is my config file and why I decide them:

```
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log 
//I need logs 
general_log = 1
slow_query_log = 1 
//to optimize queries 
//Actualy I havent any optimized query
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2 


skip-name-resolve // to increase DNS lookup performance
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 200M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 500M
// I tried with cache but nothing. 
Last setting is query_cache_size = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 52000M 
//80% actual memory
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 50 
//at least 1GB for each pool
innodb_doublewrite = OFF 
//for improve io performance 
innodb_flush_method =  O_DIRECT 
//for improve io performance with innodb_doublewrite off
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M 
//lots of little innodb write
#innodb_thread_concurrency=8 
//I try this but I can not get anything so it is now innodb decide it 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2; 
//to increase io performance. I do not need ACID
#log-bin 
// It can be dangerous but I turn it off for improve performance
```

OS top stats under load with 800 users:
    innodb_file_format=Barracuda
    innodb_file_per_table=ON

```
CPU usage: 40%-80%
IO write: 3MB-7MB
IO read: nearly 0
Ram Usage: 37GB
No swap usage and also swappines is 0.
```

Workbench stats under load with 800 users:

```
Traffic: 40MB-80MB
Connection: 820
Key Efficiency: 93,5%
Select per sec: 2000-4000
InnoDB Buffer Usage: 20.2%
InnoDB reads per sec: 0
InnoDB writes per sec 500-1500
```

I got stuck and cant go further to improve my db performance for 1500 concurrent user. What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64637/discussion-on-question-by-guneraykut-mysql-5-6-performance-tuning-issue).